# How do I locate a specific location in google map view (in android studio)?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

In my application I have few Items of List. Clicking on each list item navigates to the corresponding page.

Now I have an Item named ***Map view*** and I want that as soon as a user clicks on it, it should take a map view page and locate that address (I have mentioned in my code) in the map. How could I do that?

In fact I haven't worked with Google Map view before.

This is what I have tried: [I am not allowed to use intent].

DummyContent:

```
................................
................................
     static {
        // Add 4 sample items.
        addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Shopping center details"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Homepage"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Contact"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Map View"));
    }
.................................
..............................
```

ItemDetailFragment:

```
    .................
....................
 }else if(mItem.equals("4")){//4. Map View

                /*locate the following address in google map:
                Times Square
                Manhattan, NY 10036
                United States

                */
                 rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_detailed, container, false);
                WebView webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);

                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                 }
..............................
......................
```

fragment_map_detailed.XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you use with webview ? , you must import google service and use of MapView in api

Comment: adnan9011, there is no mapview in my android studio.

Comment: i answered your question . i have this isue before , the links is very useful .

Comment: adnan9011, thanks, i will have a look on it soon sure.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tutorials :

- 1. use google service **as library**
- 2. get google map keys in google console
- 3. create your code

[this tutorials is good](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

[this is good too](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlang2)
.title("Hospital").snippet("Example2"))
.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
```

Where:

```
LatLng latlang2 = new LatLng(25.2797674, 72.7755091);
```

Comment: Mayur R. Amipara, SORRY! what is this? is it android code?

Comment: adnan9011, but this is not explanation. this is code. can u please tell me where to put this code?

Comment: please refer google map tutorial and than look at above code its simple code that u need...